# java incorrect rainfall for year expected

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to get the mean rainfall for a certain year. When I try this I get a failure.

```
Incorrect mean rainfall for a year expected: <80.19> but was <8.341666666666667>
```

I think this means I am calculating the mean over ten years instead of a certain mean value for a specified year. But I'm not sure what to do because I ran it before and it was working and now it isn't :(

```
public double calculateMeanRainfallYear(int Year) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int counter = 0; counter < rainfallYears.length;c ounter++) {
        sum = rainfallYears[counter].calculateMeanRainfall();
    }
    return sum/rainfallYears.length;        
}
```

Comment: It seems fishy what you are doing, and your goal is also unclear from the question. You run it over some test cases (which gives you the first output), and have a mismatch. I suppose the task is the following: given a year, calculate a mean rain fall for this year. You do not use Year anywhere in your code, how would you expect to have a correct response.

Comment: I thought it was weird too. That's pretty much the task. That's given me an idea though, I'll try using getYear in the for loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `sum`, you probably wanted:

```
sum += rainfallYears[counter].calculateMeanRainfall();
```

Mind the `+`; otherwise you are just getting the last element, not summing it up.